# Setting up a TAP device on linux

Tags: linux, networking

I am trying to set up a tap device to use with [uIP](http://www.sics.se/~adam/old-uip/download.html) to do some testing/development on a Linux (Ubuntu 11.04 & 11.10)  PC.

I've gotten as far as using `tunctl` from uml-utilities to create a `/dev/tap0` device and have used `ifconfig tap0` to bring up the device to where I can ping it.

Also, when I run the uIP test program (uip-1.0/unix/uip), it will successfully open the tap0 device and can change the IP address.

So here's where I'm stuck... I would like to be able to access my uIP based program that is connected to the device 1) using ordinary client programs (web browsers, telnet, etc), and 2) access from other systems on my LAN.   From what I understand, I need to setup a bridge, but this is where I'm a little lost since most of the info online that explains how to setup a bridge is geared toward use with QEMU.

Am I on the right track here?  And can anyone point me towards the right documentation or have the rest of the solution?